# In a VB desktop program, how do you register serial keys so they can't be used more than once?

Tags: database, vb.net, serial-number

I have made a program in Visual Basic 2010, and I need a way to protect it so that when someone has purchased the program, they can't simply send the setup folder to someone else and they could use it.

From what I have read, it looks like a good way to do this is to have an online database which the program checks the serial key to see if it has already been registered, however as I'm still new to making programs, I have no idea how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the users email address and hash it (SHA1 with some salt). Once it's been used store a value in a database so you know it has already been registered. This way you don't need to worry about generating registration keys or storing them.

You'd need a mechanism if the user ever needed to re-install though, Stevens suggestion of using the machine UUID is a good example, that way they can re-install as many times on the same machine but if they install on another machine (or a new installation of windows) you'll need to verify this some other way.

Taken from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38951/How-To-Hash-Data-Using-MD5-and-SHA1

The example below doesn't add salt, this is important as it will stop people just sha1 hashing another users email and using it as a key. For example take the users email address  and add some secret text before and after:

```
Dim userEmail as string = "my@email.com"
userEmail += "s0m3s3cr3tt3xt"
UserEmail = "s0mem0r3s3cr3tt3xt" & userEmail

dim mySHA1Hash = GetSHA1HashData(userEmail)
```

**Generate SHA1 hash**

```
Private Function GetSHA1HashData(data As String) As String



    Dim sha1__1 As SHA1 = SHA1.Create()

    'convert the input text to array of bytes
    Dim hashData As Byte() = sha1__1.ComputeHash(Encoding.[Default].GetBytes(data))

    'create new instance of StringBuilder to save hashed data
    Dim returnValue As New StringBuilder()

    'loop for each byte and add it to StringBuilder
    For i As Integer = 0 To hashData.Length - 1
        returnValue.Append(hashData(i).ToString())
    Next

    ' return hexadecimal string
    Return returnValue.ToString()
End Function
```

**Validate hash**

```
Private Function ValidateSHA1HashData(inputData As String, storedHashData As String) As Boolean
    'hash input text and save it string variable
    Dim getHashInputData As String = GetSHA1HashData(inputData)

    If String.Compare(getHashInputData, storedHashData) = 0 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. Apologies I don't know anything about this hash technique. How does it prevent the program being used on another computer? Does it somehow edit the setup file? Sorry for my question probably seeming very stupid, I just have a very limited knowlege of how code works. Thanks again :)

Comment: It just avoids you having to generate and store registration/serial keys. The string 'secretUSEREMAILsecret' when hashed will always be the same, but it cannot be reversed back into that string. So you can generate a serial key based on their email address and all you have to store is their email. so at registration you could have two fields, email and serial/key which then connects to your service and validates. You'll still need a way of dealing with re-installs but using the UUID of the machine is a good technique.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of hashing because it can help you to plug a lot of holes. For instance, something that works for us is  on installation, the user has to enter their details (Company Name, etc) plus unique serial number. This is all stored in the database, plus a hash built from all those details. The company name then appears on all the reports etc. On startup the app regenerates the hash and checks it matches the stored value. If they modify anything in the db using SSMS etc (num of users, lic to date) the hash fails and the app won't run.

Comment: @peterG is correct, it's not terribly difficult to get your head around hashing, the framework takes care of the heavy lifting for you, all you need to know is what methods to call. Check out the system.security.cryptography namespace. You'll find a lots of uses for it once you've learnt the basics.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going down that road, you'll need a way to identify:

1. your users
2. machines that run your application

User identification should be pretty straightforward. Usually people know their own names and are able to type it into a textbox.

For the second problem, you could use WMI in order to get the UUID of a computer (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), which is unique for every computer.

(To access WMI services in .NET, you need to add a project reference to [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx)).

Once you have that set up, you'll need to set up your database in a way that allows it to store associations between your users' accounts and computer UUIDs.

From there on, it's just standard programming logic. On a new installation, automatically add the UUID to the database. On an existing installation, check if the UUID is still in the database. When uninstalling, remove the UUID from the database.

Depending on your licensing terms, you'll probably want to restrict a user account to `n` unique installations (UUIDs). This won't stop me from letting my mother use my login details without paying, but it will prevent mass account sharing.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. There is a lot in there that is new to me so it may take me a while to figure it all out. Is there not just a way to simply have a registration form appear when the program is first run, where the user will enter a serial key that I supply them with, and this is simply checked once against an online database to see if it has already been registered or not? Thanks again.

Comment: In that case, the only thing you really need is a key blacklist, which you maintain yourself. But then you'll spend a lot of time figuring out which keys have been leaked to the public.

Comment: Basically, replace all occurrences of "UUID" with "serial key" in my answer and you have what you're asking for. Not 100%, but the idea is pretty much the same.